# Why C++ has this poor performance extracting elements from a queue? (Comparative included)

Tags: c++, python, heap, priority-queue

I've done a quick performance test between C++ and Python standard libs (queue and heap) against my basic implementation in C. This is what I've used:

- Python 2.7.5 :: Anaconda 1.7.0 (x86_64)
- i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1
- Elements to sort are ints.

Not surprised about the performance differences on the queue construction segment (I mean creating a sorted heap from an array of elements).

[image]

Here is something strange. I don't know if I'm missing something... Why C++ takes so long extracting the elements? Is this the proper way of building a priority queue on C++?

[image]

My implementation looks like this for Python

```
# Construct the queue
heapq.heapify(int_values)

# Extract element
heapq.heappop(int_values)
```

In C++:

```
// Construct the queue
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > mypq (int_values, int_values+elements);

// Extract element
mypq.pop();
```

Here is the complete C++ code, and how I measure the time.
https://gist.github.com/srodrb/6916802

And here is the Python code:
https://gist.github.com/srodrb/6917081

Edit: **Note that I don't pretend to optimize my C++ code**, this comparative is valid to me as I'm testing the tools of the standard library out of the box. I'm just only wondering about that huge performance gap. Also I'm not contrasting C++ with Python because probably heapq call some C functions.

Comment: You need to show how you tested. Also, did you enable optimizations? (a common problem with performance-related SO questions)

Comment: No optimizations, only g++ $filename, no optimizations for Python code. I don't pretend to optimize the C++ code, I'm just wondering about that big performance gap.

Comment: There is a huge difference when turning optimizations on in C++ code. A performance benchmark without optimizations enabled is meaningless.

Comment: JesseGood is right, unless you turn on optimizations for C and C++ programs this comparison is completely meaningless.

Comment: @srodrb: We would also like to see your python code, esp how you are measuring the performance.

Comment: So, JesseGood and user2802841, that result seems normal to you? Nothing strange? Any optimizations on the code as you can see and no compiler magic. :S

Comment: When benchmarking C++, there are two things to consider: Should you **manually** optimize your code, and should **the compiler** optimize your code? The answer to the latter question should always be Yes.

Comment: @srodrb: Result looks perfectly fine to me. It's a debug build, so expensive O(N*N) `__DebugIsHeapSorted()` checks are good.

Comment: Neither your C++ nor your Python code compile as posted.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph solved, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [make_heap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) and [pop_heap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap) on an array/vector.

Comment: This *maybe* answers the second question(what's the proper way of building a heap) but it completely avoids answering the first question, which is the more interesting one.

Comment: Seems like that's basically what he's doing `The standard container adaptor priority_queue calls make_heap, push_heap and pop_heap automatically to maintain heap properties for a container.`